# Overloading ++ and += operators in dart

Tags: dart

I'm writing a code about complex numbers, but when I want to overload ++ and += operators the vscode says to me these aren't dart operators. I've made a Complex class and +, -, *, / operators work fine with this code.
Here's the code:

```
library complex_type;

import 'dart:math' as math;

class Complex<T extends num> {
  final T re;
  final T im;

  const Complex(T re, T im)
      : this.re = re,
        this.im = im;

  /// The square root of -1. A number representing "0.0 + 1.0i"
  static const I = const Complex(0, 1);

  /// A complex number representing "NaN + NaNi"
  static const NAN = const Complex(double.nan, double.nan);

  /// A complex number representing "+INF + INFi"
  static const INFINITY = const Complex(double.infinity, double.infinity);

  /// A complex number representing "1.0 + 0.0i"
  static const ONE = const Complex(1, 0);

  /// A complex number representing "0.0 + 0.0i"
  static const ZERO = const Complex(0, 0);

  num get real => re;
  num get imaginary => im;

  set re(num re) => this.re = re;
  set im(num im) => this.im = im;

  @override
  String toString() => '($re, $im)';

  @override
  bool operator ==(dynamic other) =>
      other is Complex && re == other.re && im == other.im;

  Complex<T> operator -() => Complex<T>(-1 * this.re, -1 * this.im);
  Complex<T> operator +=(Complex<T> z) => Complex<T>(this.re += z.re, this.im += z.im);
  Complex<T> operator ++() => Complex<T>(this.re++, this.im++);
  Complex<T> conjugate(Complex<T> z) => Complex<T>(z.re, -1 * z.im);

  num abs(Complex<T> z) => math.sqrt(math.pow(z.re, 2) + math.pow(z.im, 2));

  Complex<T> scalar_product(num k, Complex<T> z) =>
      Complex<T>(k * z.re, k * z.im);

  Complex<T> operator +(Complex<T> z) => Complex<T>(re + z.re, im + z.im);
  Complex<T> operator -(Complex<T> z) => Complex<T>(re - z.re, im - z.im);
  Complex<T> operator *(Complex<T> z) =>
      Complex<T>(re * z.re - im * z.im, re * z.im + im * z.re);
  Complex<T> operator /(Complex<T> z) => (z == 0)
      ? NAN
      : scalar_product(math.pow(math.pow(abs(z), 2), -1), this * conjugate(z));

  num argument() {
    num theta;
    this.re >= 0
        ? theta = math.atan(this.im / this.re)
        : theta = math.atan(this.im / this.re) + math.pi;
    return theta;
  }

  Complex<T> toPolar() => Complex<T>(abs(this), this.argument());

  List<Complex<T>> nroots(int n) {
    List<Complex<T>> zk = [];
    num real, imaginary, argument;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      argument = (this.argument() + 2 * i * math.pi) / n;
      real = math.cos(argument);
      imaginary = math.sin(argument);
      zk.add(scalar_product(
          math.pow(abs(this), 1 / n), Complex<T>(real, imaginary)));
    }
    return zk;
  }
}
```

Is it possible implements these operators as overloading code  in Dart?

Comment: afaik overriding the `+` operator is enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from the spec:

> The following names are allowed for user-defined operators: ‘<’, ‘>’, ‘<=’,‘>=’, ‘==’, ‘-’, ‘+’, ‘/’, ‘ ̃/’, ‘*’, ‘%’, ‘|’, ‘ˆ’, ‘&’, ‘<<’, ‘>>’, ‘>>>’, ‘[]=’, ‘[]’, ‘ ̃’.

10.1.1  Operators: https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.2.pdf

What you are trying to override is a compound assignment operator:

> 〈compoundAssignmentOperator〉::= ‘*=’|  ‘/=’|  ‘~/=’|  ‘%=’|  ‘+=’|  ‘-=’|  ‘<<=’|  ‘>>=’|  ‘>>>=’|  ‘&=’|  ‘^=’|  ‘|=’|  ‘??=’

Which are not possible to override. They are instead using the user-defined operator defined so the following two statement means the same:

```
x = x + 1;
x += 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

To override `++` in dart, you just need:

```
YourClass operator +(int arg) => YourClass(...);
```

Then dart will treat `a++` as a `a + 1`.

But be aware that you can't have two such functions:

```
YourClass operator +(int arg) => YourClass(...);
YourClass operator +(YourClass arg) => YourClass(...);
```

You can only have one `operator +` override method!